# DLL File check is correct inject

Tags: c++, dll

I made in C++, DLL Injector and DLL file which one will be inject to process.
But how can I test my injector correct inject my dll file? Is possible send some logs from DLL file after inject to process?
Process and DLL file is 32bit.

Comment: Debug the process you are injecting into to watch how the injection is proceeding.

Comment: Also you can use `OutputDebugString` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa

Answer (score -1):

There are probably better way but a message box and beep is provably sufficient

```
 BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hInstance = hModule;
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule); //disable unwanted thread notifications to reduce overhead
        //CreateThread(NULL, NULL, Engine, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        _beginthreadex(NULL, NULL, Engine, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        Beep(750, 500);
        MessageBox(NULL, "Hello!!\r\nInjected", "Injected", MB_OK);
        //MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello!!\r\nInjected", L"Injected", MB_OK); //unicode


    break; //break attach
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `DisableThreadLibraryCalls`, `MessageBox`, `_beginthreadex` etc from `DllMain` are a really bad idea - _"...There are significant limits on what you can safely do in a DLL entry point. ..."_ see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain